# Does Service Fabric upgrade settings applies to Service Fabric upgrade or application upgrade?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

When hosting Service Fabric cluster on Azure does upgrade policy settings (under "Fabric upgrade" menu (see screenshot)) applies to upgrade of Service Fabric itself or it applies to application upgrade?

Here are the settings:

- Upgrade timeout
- Upgrade domain timeout
- ... etc

[image]

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific and provide more details?

Comment: @OlegKarasik added screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-upgrade-version-azure#set-custom-health-polices-for-upgrades) these settings applied to Service Fabric upgrade and are unrelated to application upgrade settings.